# How to use TCP transport in pysnmp-4.4.6 version

Tags: python, tcp, snmp, pysnmp

I am using PySNMP 4.4.6 and I want to change carrier to TCP.

That means I want to poll SNMP data using TCP protocol.

I'm getting the following error when I switch carrier to TCP:

```
File "send-trap-over-ipv4-and-ipv6.py", line 76, in <module>
        transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/carrier/asyncore/dispatch.py", line 50, in runDispatcher
        raise PySnmpError('poll error: %s' % ';'.join(format_exception(*exc_info())))
    pysnmp.error.PySnmpError: poll error: Traceback (most recent call last):
    ;  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/carrier/asyncore/dispatch.py", line 46, in runDispatcher
        use_poll=True, map=self.__sockMap, count=1)
    ;  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 220, in loop
        poll_fun(timeout, map)
    ;  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 201, in poll2
        readwrite(obj, flags)
    ;  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 123, in readwrite
        obj.handle_error()
    ;  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 110, in readwrite
        obj.handle_write_event()
    ;  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/asyncore.py", line 468, in handle_write_event
        self.handle_write()
    ;  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysnmp/carrier/asyncore/dgram/base.py", line 155, in handle_write
        raise error.CarrierError('sendto() failed for %s: %s' % (transportAddress, sys.exc_info()[1]))
    ;CarrierError: sendto() failed for 172.16.152.177:162: [Errno 2] No such file or directorycaused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    caused by <class 'pysnmp.carrier.error.CarrierError'>: sendto() failed for 172.16.152.177:162: [Errno 2] No such file or directorycaused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: How did you "switch carrier to TCP"? What steps did you take? And are you sure that your SNMP Agent supports TCP communication? While not impossible that would be unusual.

Comment: i replaced SOCK_DGRAM to SOCK_STREAM.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica:
i replaced SOCK_DGRAM to SOCK_STREAM in all files and previous version of pysnmp(2.0.9) supports snmp poll over tcp connection.

Comment: You can't just do that. The API calls for sending UDP packets are not the same as the API calls for setting up a TCP socket and sending data over it, then closing it later. They're different protocols; it's not just a flag, it's a fundamentally different communication paradigm. Which documentation are you following for switching to TCP?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, pysnmp 4.x does not presently offer TCP transport support. There is an ongoing work on that matter, though. Odds are to have streaming transport support in [pysnmp 5.x](https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/projects/1).